# NodeJS passing command line arguments to forever

Tags: node.js

Im trying to pass command line arguments to forever, that I want to parse in my app.

Currently I'm starting my app like this:

```
forever start -c "node --max-old-space-size=8192 --nouse-idle-notification" /home/ubuntu/node/server.js
```

I want to be able to read some arguments in my server.js.

My code for reading:

```
var arguments = process.argv.slice(2);
console.log(arguments[0]);

if(!arguments[0]) {
    console.log("Error: Missing port.");
    process.exit(1);
}
```

But how to I tell `forever` to pass arguments that can be read inside `server.js`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [forever docs](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever#using-forever-from-the-command-line), you should use this format where you append your script arguments to the very end:

```
forever [action] [options] SCRIPT [script-options]
```

So for your example, you should be able to do this (omitting the `-c` options to make this a little more readable):

```
forever start server.js 9000 anotherarg evenanother
```

You can add the `-c` and the full path to `server.js` back into your real call, based upon your situation.